# ngModel but using the reactive forms method of validation

Tags: angular, forms, validation, reactive, ngmodel

I don't like either of Angular's form validation routes, but I'm investigating a way to combine the best of each, and am close to an answer I like.

I know that regardless whether I go the `formBuilder` or the `ngModel` route, there is an `NgForm` for the form, which has a property holding the root `FormGroup` which has a heterogeneous collection of `FormControl` objects.  HTML Elements all have an adapter object implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, and my own angular components like `<date-range-picker>` can implement the same interface and pretend to be just-another-element whose value is an arbitrarily complex object.  Each `FormControl` wraps an element, talking with it via the `ControlValueAccessor` interface so it is agnostic as to what, exactly, it is actually talking to.

I know that placing either the `ngModel` or `formControl` directive on an element will create the `FormControl` instance for that element; the element doesn't get one automatically, even though a `<form>` tag gets an `NgForm` automatically.

I know that `formBuilder` will explicitly create hollow `FormControl`s which lack the HTML element, but each has a name, and in the HTML the `formControlName` gives the HTML elements a name but no `FormControl` instance, and basically `formControlName` and `formBuilder` both talk to a service that matches the names and fills-in the hollow `FormControl` with its element.

Finally, `FormControl` is where the validators live, as well as the dirty/touched/etc. properties.

My issue with `ngModel` is the same as everyone's: validation sucks.  A custom validation is little more than the condition of an `if` statement, but `ngModel` wants me to wrap that little condition in an entire directive and stick it in the HTML on the element.  That's a lot of extra typing for an `if` statement -- you can't make a one-liner re-usable because it takes one line to use the wrapper. And cross-field validation sucks.

My issue with `formBuilder` is the assignment statements.  For a model of 12 properties I'm writing 24 lines, 12 to put the values into the form and 12 to get them back out again, in a type-unsafe manner.  That's a lot of extra typing that ngModel didn't require, and it kinda violates the DRY principle since I have to repeat the list and hierarchy of input fields in the HTML within the Typescript as well.

Lately I do this:

```
<input type=text name=foo [(ngModel)]="myModel.myProperty" />
```

with

```
@ViewChild(NgModel) mod: NgModel;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mod.control.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]);
}
```

and

```
<span class=danger *ngIf="mod?.control?.errors?.required">....
```

This gives me the best of both worlds, concision and control.

But for `<date-range-picker>` I find I still have to use the `ControlValueAccessor` boilerplate, which means I then cannot use `ngModel` to shuttle values between its small 3-property object being returned and my official 12-property model source-of-truth.  Three explicit assignment statements are needed.  I want to avoid those, and avoid more angular-specific boilerplate.

It would be easy if the `FormControl`s inside the picker's HTML could see the ngForm in the HTML using the picker, but it can't.

My question is: how does a `FormControl` register itself with an `NgForm`? `FormBuilder` doesn't take an `NgForm` as an input parameter, it 'just knows' which form to attach.  Even if there's multiple forms in the same HTML template, it gets it right. If there's a service hiding behind it that goes and finds the NgForm, can I use that service from my picker to find an NgForm that is outside of its own template?

Comment: I recommend dynamic forms take a look at this library https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms

Comment: But the form I'm making isn't dynamic at all...  Controls are hard-coded...

Comment: If you only use `ReactiveFormsModule` and not `FormsModule`, then `NgForm` doesn't exist and a `<form>` element get nothing without a directive placed on it.  Granted, 90% of the members of `NgForm` were just pass-throughs to the underlying `FormGroup` anyway.. and if you're using `ngModel` then you are importing `FormsModule` anyway...

Answer (score 2):

`FormControl`s receive the `NgForm` instance from the `ngModel` / `formControlName` constructor, which is placed there by Angular DI. This "boilerplate" in a component's decorator:

```
{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateRangePickerComponent),
    multi: true
}
```

...registers a custom component (which is implementing `ControlValueAccessor`) with the DI system.  Specifically, `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` plays the same role as the `PickerService` does here:

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(pickerService: PickerService)
```

The `multi: true` part means the injected thing isn't just one service, like the PickerService is, but is actually a group of them. `RadioControlValueAccessor`, `SelectControlValueAccessor`, and `CheckboxControlValueAccessor` sit under this umbrella, and your own `DateRangePicker` could be among them if you use the "boilerplate."  Angular selects the correct one for the job at hand when looking through an HTML template.

Wrapping a component in a lambda for `forwardRef` just solves a small order-of-initialization issue, nothing more.

Basically,  implementing `ControlValueAccessor` makes a class *what* Angular expects, and the decorator specifies *where* in Angular to put it.

**But if you really don't want to use it...**

Use a template reference var on the form in the parent's HTML, and pass it to child component like it was any other value:

```
<form #theForm="ngForm" ...
    <date-range-picker [form]="theForm" ...
```

In the child component, accept the form like any other input, and also grab a reference to the ngModel used in the child's HTML (which you've already done for validator purposes):

```
@Input() form: NgForm;
@ViewChild(NgModel) mod: NgModel;
```

Add one to the other imperatively.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mod.control.setValidators([Validators.required, c => c.value.duration != 0]);
    this.form.addControl(this.mod);
}
```

And you're basically done.  There may be issues with `*ngIf` destroying and re-creating said control, or change detection not being as thorough as it normally would be, but solving these issues in this way means you're effectively re-inventing Angular.

This starts to become apparent when you have multiple ngModels in a child's template:

```
@ViewChildren(NgModel) ngModels: QueryList<NgModel>;

readonly validations = {
    'reasonField': [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(500)],
    'durationField': [Validators.required, c => c.value.duration != 0],
};

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngModels.forEach(ngModel => {
        ngModel.control.setValidators(this.validations[ngModel.name]);
        this.form.addControl(ngModel);
    });
}
```

..and now tying the validations to the fields starts to look a lot like `formBuilder` all over again. (Without the 24 assignment statements.)

Comment: the docs say that in `ngAfterViewInit()` `this.form.controls` is empty, and that's true. But we can still `addControl` at that point, and if it weren't for the input-in-child-component complication, we wouldn't need to reference `.controls` or `.addControl` at all since `ngModel` will do it on the next tick.